# HTML / JS Simplification

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a hell of a time working on a dropdown menu for a client. I think my code is way too complex for what it is. I need a resolution/alternative way to perform the given objective.

```
<font id="l1b" size="4" color="black" style="cursor:pointer; color:black;"
    onclick="showSubMenu('cat2');
    document.getElementById('cat1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('cat3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('cat4').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pa1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pb1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pc1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pd1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pa2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pb2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pc2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pd2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('da2a').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('da2b').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('da2c').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('da2d').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('da2e').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('da2f').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('da2g').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('da2h').style.display = 'none';">Tea Bags<img src="arrow.png" style="position:relative; left:8px; top:3px;"></font>
```

Here's a pic of the concept: http://robstest.mydnd.com/helppic.php

First person to help gets 10 brownie points! :D

Comment: You might have better luck over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jQuery to speed things up? You could then just loop through a list of the IDs and set display to none.  There are also lots of jQuery plugins that provide UI capabilities such as drop-downs.

Comment: Woah, a font tag.  Haven't seen one o' them in a while.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention- I am new to web developing and don't know a whole lot about javascript or jquery

Comment: Check out Google's HTML, CSS and JavaScript from the ground up: http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/ it's a fairly comprehensive look at front end development.

Comment: Would someone be willing to have a look at my actual source code? iI have tried using the code people have posted here but it doesn't seem to work :/ (I will be re-posting this thread to all the other noobies I know, I'm sure that I'm not the only person with this problem or similar.) Thanks for all the replyies guys!

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the benefits of using a library such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to make your life easier:

**Pure JavaScript**

```
var elementList = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'pa1', ... , 'da2h'];
function showSubMenu(el) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
        if (elementList[i] != el) {
            document.getElementById(elementList[i]).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var elementList = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'pa1', ... , 'da2h'];
function showSubMenu(el) {
    $.each(elementList, function() {
        if (this != el) {
            $('#' + this).css({display: "none"});
        }
    }
}
```

This tutorial might also be helpful: http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a JQuery dropdown tutorial that does something similar to what you want:

http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/

... you can also download the files and modify them to your needs.

It would be a good exercise for you to play around with and learn while you are making your project.

(Plus you may want to look at some other implementations of dropdowns to get an idea of best practices - the UI you have mocked up looks a little confusing for an end user)

Answer (score 0):

Get the child elements and loop through them, setting the display for each.  Stuff this into a function such as yourfunction(parentDiv), and apply to the on-click event after a semi-colon.

I would type up this code, but right now I don't have enough material to work with.

Comment: Dude if i was to send you my source code do you think you could help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#l1b").children().each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't look like he's trying to hide `l1b`'s children. I think they are siblings...